# How to set div with position relative

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<div>` with an `background-image`. In this `<div>` I need to Picture (2 arrows). Now I want to set this picture over the `background-image`, but it works only with `position: absolute`.

I need this with `position: relative`, because when I set it with `position: absolute`, I don't get the scrollbar.

It should look like a gallery. The `<div>` "Pfeillinks" should be on the left side and the next one "pfeilrechts" (not in the script) should be on the right side.

CSS:

```
#galerie {
    border: 0px solid #ff0000;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 70vh;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

#flexportfoliogalerie {
    display: flex;
    width: 83vw;
    border: 0px solid #ffff00;
    margin-left: 0vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#portfoliogalerieoverview {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 10vh;
    border: 0px solid #0fffff;
    z-index:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#portfoliogaleriefull {
    width: 82vw;
    height: 50vh;
    max-height: 50vh;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}

#spacegalerieoverview {
    width: 1vw;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id = 'galerie'>
    <div id = 'flexportfoliogalerie'>

        <script>
            for (i = 0; i<count;i++)
            {
                  document.write("<div id = 'portfoliogalerieoverview' style = 'background-size: contain; background-image: url(./admin/cms/bx/"+kl_bild_array[i]+"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'></div><div id = 'spacegalerieoverview'></div>");
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <br>
    <script>
          document.write("<div id = 'portfoliogaleriefull' style = ' background-size: contain; background-image: url(./admin/cms/bx/"+gr_bild_array[0]+"); background-repeat: no-repeat;'><div id = 'pfeillinks' style = 'background-image: url(./images/links.png); background-repeat: no-repeat;'></div>");
    </script>
    <div id = 'galerietext'>
        <script>
              document.write("<span style = 'font-family: sensation;'>"+bez_bild_array[0]+"</span>");
        </script>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to do it in javascript

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example.

```css
.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 250px;
  background: url(http://acadtech.gwu.edu/sites/acadtech.gwu.edu/files/image/13030015p3-app%20icons.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.gallery .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.gallery .icon.next {
  right: 0px;
}
.gallery .icon.previous {
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">

  <img class="icon next" src="http://www.keyano.ca/DesktopModules/LiveRotator/Resources/Images/NavigationImages/Default-next.png" alt="" />
  <img class="icon previous" src="http://www.keyano.ca/DesktopModules/LiveRotator/Resources/Images/NavigationImages/Default-prev.png" alt="" />


</div>
```